# Strange chain of exceptions in EF 6.4.4 on SQL Select

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

We have a very strange thread of exceptions in EF 6.4.4:

1. New transaction is not allowed because there are other threads running in the session.
   On a random SQL Select

   ```
    SELECT TOP (1) 
    [Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
    ...
    WHERE ([Extent1].[IsActive] = 1) AND ([Extent1].[Id] = @p__linq__0) failed with exception System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): New transaction is not allowed because there are other threads running in the session.
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryConsumeMetaData()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.get_MetaData()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString, Boolean isInternal, Boolean forDescribeParameterEncryption, Boolean shouldCacheForAlwaysEncrypted)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean inRetry, SqlDataReader ds, Boolean describeParameterEncryptionRequest)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean& usedCache, Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean inRetry)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior, String method)
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.InternalDispatcher`1.Dispatch[TTarget,TInterceptionContext,TResult](TTarget target, Func`3 operation, TInterceptionContext interceptionContext, Action`3 executing, Action`3 executed)
   ```

   ClientConnectionId:017da64d-9860-4200-b2bc-2ff921cf1333
   Error Number:3988,State:1,Class:16
2. Then, in the next 5-10-15 minutes we get a series of very strange exceptions on casting:
   for example:
   Specified cast is not valid.
   or

The specified cast from a materialized 'System.Int32' type to the 'System.Guid' type is not valid.

```
System.InvalidOperationException:
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.Internal.Materialization.Shaper+ErrorHandlingValueReader`1.GetValue (EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089)
   at lambda_method (Anonymously Hosted DynamicMethods Assembly, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.Internal.Materialization.Coordinator`1.ReadNextElement (EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.Internal.Materialization.Shaper`1+SimpleEnumerator.MoveNext (EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.SingleOrDefault (System.Core, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbSetMigrationsExtensions.AddOrUpdate (EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbSetMigrationsExtensions.AddOrUpdate (EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089)
   at Redacted.Infrastructure.Data.QueryRepository.StockStateQueryRepository.RegisterStockState (Redacted.Infrastructure, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null: D:\a\72\s\Redacted.Infrastructure\Data\QueryRepository\StockStateQueryRepository.cs:36)
   at Redacted.Infrastructure.Messaging.StockStateEventHandler.RegisterStockState (Redacted.Infrastructure, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null: D:\a\72\s\Redacted.Infrastructure\Messaging\StockStateEventHandler.cs:564)
   at Redacted.Infrastructure.Messaging.StockStateEventHandler.Handle (Redacted.Infrastructure, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null: D:\a\72\s\Redacted.Infrastructure\Messaging\StockStateEventHandler.cs:372)
   at Redacted.Infrastructure.Messaging.LazyEventHandler.Handle (Redacted.Infrastructure, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null: D:\a\72\s\Redacted.Infrastructure\Messaging\LazyEventHandler.cs:46)
```

It looks like after this issue, something goes wrong in System.Data.Entity and the mappings between SQL fields and EF models is broken. I have a clear example where we map in code a column of type int? to null, in database it is nullable int, works ok in normal circumstances but after the exception at 1 we get the materialization exception.

We do not use any transactions in EF code, there was no deadlock. And it happens randomly 2-3 times a day. Deployment is on Azure web app .net framework 4.8.

How we use db context:

```
 public class DbContextFactory : IDbContextFactory, IDisposable
    {
        Func<IDbContext> dbContextresolver;
        ConcurrentDictionary<int, IDbContext> dbContexts;

        public DbContextFactory([Dependency(nameof(dbContextresolver))]Func<IDbContext> dbContextresolver)
        {
            this.dbContextresolver = dbContextresolver;
            this.dbContexts = new ConcurrentDictionary<int, IDbContext>();
        }

        public IDbContext Resolve()
        {
            return dbContexts.GetOrAdd(Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId, dbContextresolver());
        }

        public IDbContext CreateDisposable()
        {
            return dbContextresolver();
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            dbContexts.ForEach(c=> c.Value.Dispose());
        }
    }

    public interface IDbContextFactory
    {
        IDbContext CreateDisposable();
        IDbContext Resolve();
    }
```

and in repos:
[image]

Comment: Sounds like you are reusing the same `DbContext` in different threads, but without seeing relevant code it's hard to say

Comment: @Charlieface I've updated the question with the code

Comment: Well a concurrent dictionary of contexts is certainly suspicious. Unless you are locking it, or you are not using `async` anywhere at all then you could run into issues. This is not the way they are supposed to be used. Create a context when you need it and dispose with `using` *on the same thread and in the same async execution flow*

Comment: we are not using async anywhere. it is quite old, but we did not have any issues with it so far. Could you have collisions in ManagedThreadId?

Comment: Did you check log files on SQL Server?  Us SSMS and check log files under Management in the explorer.